# How can we append range on pyplot graphs from csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph from csv file where row[0] is the starting time of execution and row[1] is the ending time of execution. row[6] is the amount of data transferred.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import csv

np.random.seed(0)
x=[]
y=[]
with open('graph.csv','r') as csvfile :
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots :
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[6])

plt.plot(x,y,marker='o')
plt.title("Input/Output graph of Virtual file system layer and ext4 layer read and writes.")
plt.xlabel("time(ms)")
plt.ylabel("bytes")
plt.show()
```

I would like to write `x.append(row[0]:row[1])` to show the range but python doesn't allow me to do it. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your kind cooperation. 
Below you can find answer to my question:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('graph.csv','r') as csvfile :
    rows = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))[1:]
    rows.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[6])) 
    for row in rows:
        start, end, data = int(row[0]), int(row[1]), int(row[6])
        x = [start, end]
        y = [data, data]
        plt.plot(x, y, color = 'b', marker='o')
plt.xlabel('time(milliseconds)')
plt.ylabel('Amount of Data(bytes)')
plt.title('VFS layer Read only graph')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('VR.png')
plt.show()
```

And the graph is : 
[image: Virtual file system layer input/output graph]

Answer (score 1):

Doing something like `var:var2` is not valid syntax in the context that you're using it. If you're trying to group together a pair of data points for each item in a list, you could use the tuple type for each entry and do something like this:

```
events = []

# Run this in your loop:
events.append((row[0], row[1]))
```

However, this may actually be a good use case for the ``namedtuple`][1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) type, though. Named tuples let you quickly and easily create an object that uses named attributes but still behaves like a tuple.

Here's an example of how you could use it:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import csv

np.random.seed(0)
Event = namedtuple('Event', ['start', 'end', 'transferred'])
events = []

# Assigning the points to a list
with open('graph.csv','r') as csvfile :
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in plots:
            # You can optionally omit the keywords if you use the same order
            # as defined in the namedtuple initially.
            new_event = Event(start=row[0], end=row[1], transferred=row[6])
            events.append(new_event)

# Accessing the stored events later
for event in events:
    print("({}-{} ({} transferred)").format(event.start, event.end, event.transferred)
```

Comment: row[0] is the starting time and row[1] is the finishing time. row[6] is the amount of information. You didn't mention row[1] at all in your program?

Comment: @NagmatNazarov, apologies I misunderstood the original question. I've revised it now. I'm still not entirely sure that I understand what you're trying to do, so please let me know if I'm missing something.